# Fetch all the documents has reference to a certain document in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I need all the documents from different collections that have reference to a certain "parent" document. Any easy workaround?

My naive approach would be to loop all the collections and loop all the documents and check the condition. Any easier / more efficient way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My naive approach would be to loop all the collections and loop all the documents and check the condition. Any easier / more efficient way?

Well, without the data model that is hard to answer, but the reference could have an index, right? I mean you know which field *is* the reference? For example,

```
Users (parent) { 
  Id : ObjectId("123"),
  ...
}

Comments {
  Id : ObjectId("abc"),
  UserId : ObjectId("123"),
  ... 
}

Questions {
  Id : ObjectId("efc"),
  UserId : ObjectId("123"),
  ... 
}
```

Then, knowing that `UserId` is the reference, you can call `db.Comments.find({ UserId : ObjectId("123") })` and find all references. That way, you don't have to loop through *all* documents. The only thing you need is a lookup table `collection name -> name of the reference field`

Comment: I would not use any schema on server side, so something that assume the most general situtation

Comment: `but the reference could have an index, right` .. yes, I guess .. but then some kind of schema needs

Comment: This should be well in the application domain. Otherwise, the problem is that you'll never know what constitutes a reference and what doesn't, but you can certainly still loop through all the data and rely on the uniqueness of the keys. But that all sounds quite ugly.